# How to set a date picker using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to set a date on a website that has a datepicker. See the code on the website below.

```
<div id="pickup-date" class="date date-time-field">
```

So I am trying to set the value of "pickup-date" with the vba code below

```
appIE.document.getElementbyid("pickup-date").Value = Format(Date, "12/20/17")
```

I receive Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method.
Am I able to set a date for "pickup-date"? If yes then what should my VBA code be?

Comment: Just a guess but you could try .innerHTML instead of .Value

Comment: @Absinthe Excellent guess! It is putting the date in the correct position . Now all I have to do is work out the date format which the site will accept.

Comment: Glad I could help. Just for reference, your HTML object (appIE) will usually use HTML properties rather than VBA style properties so if you get stuck just look up the HTML to do what you need to.